# Probability involving 3 standard normal random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

> If $X,Y,Z$ are independent standard normal random variables, compute
>   $P(3X+2Y<6Z-7)$.

One way is to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{(6z-2y-7)/3}\frac{\exp(-(x^2+y^2+z^2)/2)}{2\pi\sqrt{2\pi}}dxdydz.$$ But I don't know how to calculate this.

Comment: Another way is to use the fact that any linear combination of independent normal random variables is a normal random variable again.

Comment: I was thinking something along that line. So 3X+2Y~N(0,5) and 6Z-7~N(-7,6) isn't it? Then we have to calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{\infty}^a\frac{e^{-b^2/50}}{5\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{e^{-(a+7)^2/72}}{6\sqrt{2\pi}}dbda$$ I can't figure out this one either.

Comment: Hint: The probability is $P[3X+2Y-6Z<-7]$.

Comment: I think I got it. 3X+2Y-6Z~N(0,-1), so $P(3X+2Y-6Z<-7)=P(A>7)$ where $A$ is the standard normal random variable. So the answer is $1-\Phi(7)$. Is it correct?

Comment: Wait, the variance can't be negative, can it? So it should be $3X+2Y-6Z~N(0,11)$?

Comment: See my answer below for how to combine the variances.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two independent normally distributed random variables, then the distribution of their sum is also normally distributed, where:

$$\mu=\mu_1+\mu_2$$

$$\sigma^2=\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2$$

You can use this to solve your problem without integrals, other than one evaluation of the error function.  Actually, you don't even need that, since the $7$ turns out to give you a special result for which you probably already know the result of applying the error function.

Comment: To be precise, you should either insert *jointly* after "two" or simply replace the latter with the former.

Comment: I have updated the answer to say "independent".  I realize that that is slightly stronger than "jointly", but is likely more widely understood than "jointly".  You are right that I had to say something more about the relation between the two distributions to make the statement correct.